# Make everything smaller on macOS

Tags: macos, screen, resolution

I just switched from Windows to Mac. I got a Macbook Air M2.

I find that everything is really big even after adjusting the resolution to 'more space'. This is especially true for apps.

[image]

I'm coming from a Huawei Matebook 13-inch screen which seems to have tons more space.

Is there some way to make everything smaller?

Comment: Does `Advanced...` have `Show resolutions as a list`? If so, that will give you more choices.